# Download Button Not doing anything in IE and firefox for excel file

Tags: html

I have created a download button , which will download a .xlsx file.
The same is working perfectly in chrome , but not doing anything in IE and Firefox.  I donot able to understand the exact problem here .

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse visible-xs">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
              </button>

          <div><br/><br/><br/></div><br/>
    <div align="center">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3><?php echo $dirname; ?> Cities Charts <?php echo $project; ?></h3><button class="col-sm-offset-11 btn btn-success"><a href="/NT_Dashboard_withDB/Dashboard_Additional_Information.xlsx" download>Download Data</a></button></div></br></br>
        <div id="bodyContent" class="panel-body"></div></br></br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: which version of IE and firefox u on?

Comment: Try to update your other browsers

Comment: The [`download` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Browser_compatibility) isn't supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

according to HTML syntax `button` cannot have `<a>` tag inside of it.

to solve your problem  you can use `<a >` outside button or use `javascript`

```
<a href="/NT_Dashboard_withDB/Dashboard_Additional_Information.xlsx" download>Download Data<button class="col-sm-offset-11 btn btn-success"></button></a>
```

*javascript:*

```
<button class="col-sm-offset-11 btn btn-success" onClick="javascript:window.location='/NT_Dashboard_withDB/Dashboard_Additional_Information.xlsx'></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is support for the HTML5 `download` attribute.  IE doesn't support it and older versions of Firefox may not support it either.

https://caniuse.com/#search=download

Comment: who said op is using older version of the two?

Comment: The OP did, @MasivuyeCokile.

Comment: *I have created a download button , which will download a .xlsx file. The same is working perfectly in chrome , but not doing anything in IE and Firefox.* where exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "button" tag to wrap "a" tag you can style  tag as shown below.

```html
<div class="panel-heading">
<h3><?php echo $dirname; ?> Cities Charts <?php echo $project; ?></h3>
  <a href="/NT_Dashboard_withDB/Dashboard_Additional_Information.xlsx" class="col-sm-offset-11 btn btn-success" download>Download Data</a>
</div>
```

This will work for you.